# Using jQuery to flip a panel on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, flip

Using the [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) plugin or a [similar one](http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/), I'm trying to create a simple div that flips over on mouse over, and flips back once the mouse leaves. I have created a proof of concept simple webpage, but I cant seem to get it to work. If implemented in the most simple way (mouseenter: flip(), mouseleave: revertFlip()), The div repeatedly flips while your mouse moves. With a bit of work, I can make it work simply, but there is the issue that if you move your mouse off before the animation finishes it gets stuck. After much experimentation, my code looks as such;

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src='jquery-ui\jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
        <script src='jquery-ui\ui\jquery-ui.js'></script>
        <script src='jquery.flip.js'> </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flipper"><div class="panel">Not flipped!</div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {display:inline-block;}

.panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom:-20px;
}

.flipper{
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

**javaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flipper').mouseenter(function(){
        console.log('--Mouse Entered--');
        console.log('NOT flipped ' + !($(this).children().hasClass('flipped')));
        console.log('NOT flip ' + !($(this).children().hasClass('flip')));
        if (!($(this).children().hasClass('flipped')) && !($(this).children().hasClass('flip'))) {
            console.log('If evaluated')
            $(this).children().addClass('flip');
            console.log('Added flip')
            $(this).children().flip({
                direction: 'lr',
                content: 'Flipped!',
                color: 'blue',
                speed: 1000,
                onEnd: function(){
                    console.log('Ended. Removed flip, added flipped');
                    $(this).children().removeClass('flip');
                    $(this).children().addClass('flipped');
                    console.log('Does it have flip ' + $(this).children().hasClass('flip'))
                }
            });
        };
    });
    $('.flipper').mouseleave(function(){
        console.log('--Mouse left--');
        if ($(this).children().hasClass('flipped')) {
        $(this).children().flip({
            direction: 'rl',
            content: 'Not flipped!',
            color: 'red',
            speed: 100
        });
        $(this).children().removeClass('flipped');
        console.log('Removed flipped')
        }

    });
    $('.flipper').click(function(){
        console.log('DEBUG classes "' + $(this).children().attr('class') + '"');
    });
});
```

Currently, the div flips once, then refuses to remove the 'flip' class, despite saying it has.
At this point, I'm very confused and lost. I just want my div to flip. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [JQuery Timing API](http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/api/wait/.wait_deferred.html) to wait for mouseenter function to complete before executing mouseout function.

or you can also do something like this to wait 2 seconds for mouseout function to execute.

```
$('.flipper').mouseout(function(){
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('--Mouse left--');
        if ($('.flipper').children().hasClass('flipped')) {

            $(this).children().flip({
                    direction: 'rl',
                    content: 'Not flipped!',
                    color: 'red',
                    speed: 100
            });
            $('.flipper').children().removeClass('flipped');
            $('.flipper').children().removeClass('flip');
            console.log('Removed flipped')
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Whoops. Forgot to change mouseout back to mouseleave. Should still work. Could you explain how I would use the timing .wait()? I'm not sure how to implement it.